# Android parse a very simple XML Array

Tags: android

This might sound dumb, but I just need the help with the logic,
I have this very simple XML array:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>Lisa Jackson</string>
    <string>Elisabeth Hartmann</string>
    <string>C. J. Sansom</string>
    <string>Irmengard Gabler</string>
    <string>Oliver Pötzsch</string>
    <string>Ulla Illerhaus</string>
    <string>Christopher J. Sansom</string>
    <string>Nina Blazon</string>
    <string>Nicholas Lessing</string>
    <string>Johannes Steck</string>
    <string>Peter Kaempfe</string>
    <string>Dimeter Inkiow</string>
    <string>Barbara Sher</string>
    <string>Ulrike Hübschmann</string>
    <string>Otfried Preußler</string>
    <string>Ulla Illerhaus</string>
    <string>Annette Kurth</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

but when I try to parse it this way:

```
static final String KEY_ITEM = "string";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    map.put(KEY_ITEM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM));
    menuItems.add(map);
}
```

It displays the list based on the number of the given  (17 list items) on the XML file, but it doesn't display any of the content, like 'Lisa Jackson', 'Elisabeth Hartmann', etc.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: 1) what kind of xmlparser are you using (please add part of file header into your example)

Comment: 2) you're trying to get "string" value on the chosen "string" element. isn't there any method how to obtain element's value instead of querying of the value of subkey or parameter or whatever it is?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/. To number 2 that's why I'm a bit clueless in this case. Thx

Comment: You have different xml structure: try to study funtion specification for the object [Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html): here you need to call e.getNodeValue() instead of parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM): Look to your code: you're finding <string> element inside your strin element, which is wrong.

Comment: You can try to use another simplexmlframework to deal with you issue

Comment: @V-X So I called this: map.put(KEY_ITEM, e.getNodeValue()); but still it doesn't display the value of <string>

Comment: try a bit of debuging. this must be very easy. (Or make your situation more like the one in the example: <array><person><name>Lisa Jackson</name></person>...</string> and list all persons and display their names...)

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

```
element.getTextContent();
```

This will get the text value needed.

OR

```
for (int in = 0; in < numberOfChildren; in++) {
    Node node = nl.item(in);
    Log.d("skt",node.getNodeName() + " = " + node.getTextContent());
    //node.getTextContent() has the text. Add it to map
}
```